# Resume a suspended process in a for loop

Tags: bash

I am running in bash:

```
for i in ull-*.pbm; do convert $i tmp2/$i.pdf ; done
```

I `Ctrl-Z` in the middle of running, and then `fg` its job id. But the remaining iterations do not continue to finish. I wonder why?

Comment: I can confirm that for `for i in *.txt; do echo "$i"; sleep 0.5 ; done` (GNU bash, Version 4.2.53)

Answer (score 13):

`Ctrl-Z` suspends the currently running process. In expression

```
for i in ull-*.pbm; do convert "$i" "tmp2/$i.pdf" ; done
```

all commands except `convert` (i.e. `for`, `in`, `do` and `done`) are `bash`'s keywords running in the current shell and shell cannot suspend itself (and it is not your intention anyhow). So when you hit `Ctrl-Z`, and command `convert` suspends, the loop will simply quit as there is nothing to process anymore.

If you want to be able to suspend the whole loop then just run it in the subshell environment:

```
(for i in ull-*.pbm; do convert "$i" "tmp2/$i.pdf" ; done)
```

The only shell I know that is capable of suspending the whole loop in the current shell is `zsh`.

Comment: Nope, the `Ctrl-Z` could just suspend the one convert instance, there is no reason why the loop couldn't continue and start another. For some reason `bash` stops the loop. When I test in `dash` the loop continues, other shells probably do the same.

Comment: @Graeme continuing the loop with one iteration suspended seems dangerous to me as next step can depend on the previous. The only reasonable solution for me is to suspend the whole loop and it could be done in subshell (actually `zsh` is able to suspend the whole loop running in current shell).

Comment: That's probably the answer - the `bash` developers likely had the same opinion as you. Continuing the loop is still what I would have expected though, when you stop the process and hand control back to the shell it seems natural for it to pick up where it left off (and would probably be the behaviour in `bash` if they didn't add code to do something else).